# Installing Android Support Library v7 Appcompat results in errors in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to install Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat in Visual Studio's NuGet Manager on a clean project, but each time that I do there are over 100 errors. I tried to clearing my NuGet cache under NuGet Package Manager, then re-installing all the packages. This works but when I close and re-open my solution, the errors come back. Also, there are yellow triangles under my references when re-opening with support.v7.appcompat installed.

Has anyone else dealt with this issue?

Comment: It would help if you at least show us your error. Well, you can try to check the minimum requirement for the Nuget, or try to use Clean, then rebuild solution, etc. About warning (yellow triangles), usually i got it from outdated xamarin.forms nuget.

Comment: @Godya Aditya How did you update the forms?

Comment: right click your namespace, ManageNugetPackage, at Nuget Package Manager, you will find 3 tab (Browse, Installed, Update), click update. Update the package you want.